# Generate custom property in Visual Studio C#

Tags: visual-studio, code-generation

quick question.
From Visual Studio, I'd like to generate a custom property from the selected variable. Example considering the following variable declaration:

```
        string test;
```

I'd like to be able to generate the following property:

```
    public string Test
    {
        get { return test; }
        set { test = value; FirePropertyChanged("Test"); }
    }
```

Some solutions exist in Visual Studio natively but don't include "FirePropertyChanged".
Not sure if I have to create a custom snippet or VSIX package...

Waiting for your suggestions.
Thank you in advance.